Exclude decorators in pdoc documentation
I would like to exclude decorators from my API documentation using pdoc. Is there any possible way I can achieve that?
For an example, if I write:
@xl_func("blah", "blah")
def examples_are_blah()
     print("blah")


I get the following output:

The decorator function xl_func I would like to delete from the documentation output, given that it sometimes contains a lot of parameters that are not adding any specific value for the documentation.

Can you add some examples?

pdoc's HTML output has the decorator as
<div class="decorator">@cache</div>

The easiest way to hide those would be with custom CSS as a custom template. You can create a custom.css file in an empty directory:
.decorator {
    display: none;
}

and then run pdoc --template-directory ./your-template-directory ....
Ref: https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html#edit-pdocs-html-template
